# Are USC applications allowed to install .desktop files?

Tags: software-center, application-development, icons, packaging, deb

[Ubuntu's official site for developers](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/my-apps-packages/) says:

```
Technical requirements:

In order for your application to be distributed in the Software Centre it must:

Be in one, self-contained directory when installed
Be able to be installed into the /opt/<package-name> directory (*)
Be executable by all users from the /opt/<package-name> directory (**)
Write all configuration settings to ~/.config/<package-name> 
(This can be one file or a directory containing multiple configuration files)
```

But what about .desktop files and icons ? What about symlinks from /usr/bin ? Are these allowed?